# my code is getting submitted successfully but giving SIGSEGV error when trying to run the code on code chef

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int x,y,m;
        cin>>m>>x>>y;
        int copHouseNo,run=x*y,count=0;
        bool house[101];
        memset(house,1,sizeof(house));
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            cin>>copHouseNo;
            for(int j=copHouseNo;j<=100 && j<=copHouseNo+run;j++)
                house[j]=0;
            for(int j=copHouseNo;j>=copHouseNo-run && j>=1;j--)
                house[j]=0;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            if(house[i])
                count++;
       cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand two things-

1. How it is accessing invalid memory?
2. It is giving runtime error but successfully admitted?

Thank in advance

Comment: "Code compiled successfully" means nothing, especially if you don't treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Suggestion: Print out all of the loop bounds and make sure they don't breach the array.

Comment: Where is your error/bounds checking? Do you know what the inputs are? Do you trust that those will _always_ be valid inputs? What does "successfully admitted" mean and what does that have to do with runtime errors?

Comment: `house` does not contain valid booleans, and your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you have or can determine an input that makes your program fail you will have a much easier time debugging. For example, you could be able to run the program in a debugger and see the crash firsthand. Also consider replacing `bool house[101];` and `memset(house,1,sizeof(house));` with `std::vector<bool> house(101, true);` and taking advantage of the `at` method while debugging. The code will run more slowly, but that's mostly because it's performing bounds checks.

Comment: A description of the problem you're trying to solve would be handy.

Comment: HI this is the link to problem- https://www.codechef.com/problems/COPS

Comment: @user4581301 thanks it is getting run successfully now..but i  didn't get what was the issue with using boolean array?

Comment: If it's working now without changing anything else, you're just getting unlucky. Back the code up and then replace all of the uses of `[]` with `.at()` and see if you can catch a buffer overflow.